# PHP - How to navigate this array dynamically

Tags: php, arrays

Have an issue with the following array... I can't navigate it using $arrayname[0]... it has to be $arrayname[111]... Is there a way to make this work the first way? That first number is dynamic.

```
array(1) { [111]=> object(stdClass)#202 (24) { 
    ["ID"]=> int(111)
    ["post_author"]=> string(1)"2"
    ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2011-03-18 14:36:08"
    ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2011-03-18 18:36:08"
    ["post_content"]=> string(0) ""
    ["post_title"]=> string(23) "Kyle Hotchkiss' Mugshot"
    ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) ""
    ["post_status"]=> string(7) "inherit"
    ["comment_status"]=> string(4) "open"
    ["ping_status"]=> string(4) "open" ["post_password"]=> string(0) ""
    ["post_name"]=> string(18) "mugshot_khotchkiss" ["to_ping"]=> string(0) "" ["pinged"]=> string(0) ""
    ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2011-03-18 14:36:08"
    ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2011-03-18 18:36:08" ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) ""
    ["post_parent"]=> int(106)
    ["guid"]=> string(66) "http://hotchkissmade.com/wp-content/uploads/mugshot_khotchkiss.jpg"
    ["menu_order"]=> int(0)
    ["post_type"]=> string(10) "attachment"
    ["post_mime_type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg"
    ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0"
    ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw"
} }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-shift.php gives you the first element in the array. It seems that your Tool stores the array-entry at the id (111). Are there any other elements in the array at anytime?

Comment: Yes, `array_shift` is the best option if there is only one element and you can discard the array.

Comment: @Kyle-Hotchkiss I'm glad the answer helped you!

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach ($arrayname as $foo)
{
 // profit
}
```

Or you can just:

```
$arrayname = array_values($arrayname); // resort to 0 ... n-1
```

Whichever you prefer.